# Changing #N/A values in Excel to last non-error value in the spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I have a set of values that look like this:

```
Time        DataSet1        DataSet2
00:10:00    15              27
00:20:00    #N/A            25
00:30:00    33              45
00:40:00    #N/A            #N/A
00:50:00    #N/A            25
01:00:00    #N/A            12
```

Now, I want to fill all #N/A values with the previous valid value in the table. For example: the value for DataSet1 at 00:40:00, 00:50:00 and 01:00:00 should be 33. How does one do that?

Comment: The #N/A are from a formula as I import timestamped data from other spreadsheets but there are not values for every time slot on the other sheets. No blanks need to be preserved, #N/A's just need to be replaced by the previous valid value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the area you want to fix and run this macro:

```
Sub FixData()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        If r.Text = "#N/A" Then
            r.Value = r.Offset(-1, 0).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

For example, before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
=IF(ISERROR(<yourformulahere>),A1,<yourformulahere>)
```

Autofill from A2 to your last row.

Will only work if yourformula is "autofillable". (:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093349

Comment: In Excel 2007 and later you can simplify this to: `=IFERROR(<yourformulahere>,A1)`

Answer (score 1):

1. Select A1 then tap <kbd>F5</kbd> and when the **GoTo** dialog appears, click <kbd>Special</kbd>.
2. Check *Formulas* and uncheck everything but *Errors*.
3. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
4. Type <kbd>=</kbd> then <kbd>↑</kbd> and finalize with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The errors should be converted to the value above.

Comment: @pnuts - Yes, I was relying on the sample data to determine that ambiguity. Perhaps the OP wanted `#DIV/0!` converted as well ...?

Comment: This really is a brilliant solution! I did however find problems in that it didn't always update all the values that were errors even though I used ctrl + enter. That may be a Excel bug or something though and not a problem with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you prefer a macro-way:

```
Dim val As String
Dim col_to_check As Long, cnt As Long

col_to_check = 2 ' We check the 2nd column
cnt = 1 ' We'll use it to check rows below

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 If IsError(Cells(i, col_to_check)) Then
   val = Cells(i - 1, col_to_check)
   Cells(i, col_to_check) = val
   While IsError(Cells(i + cnt, col_to_check))
     Cells(i + cnt, col_to_check) = val
     cnt = cnt + 1
   Wend
 End If
 i = i + cnt - 1
 cnt = 1
Next i
```

Answer (score -2):

We need to fill in "#N/A" cells with a formula `=above cell address`.

1. CTRL+F
2. Type #N/A
3. Click Find All
4. Highlight all with mouse as picture below.
5. Click on one space above menu - see oval (do not close Find and Replace window)
6. Start typing `=` and `press Up key`.
7. Press CTRL+Enter
8. Copy and paste all as text, to get rid of formulas.

[image]

Comment: MS Office Professional Plus 2010. Version 14.0.7143.5000 32-bit

Comment: This should work on 2013 as well, check the steps, clarified it a bit more. Yes, also updated the picture.

Comment: if it is a formula, then copy paste as text, then follow my steps, or use @Jeeped `GoTo` solution. Logic is the same.