# Selecting Range for a Loop and Changing N/A Values to Latest Numeric Value

Tags: vba, for-loop, range

I use this code in an attempt to clean potential N/A values in one of the columns.

```
Sub FixData()
Dim r As Range

Range("AL7").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

For Each r In Selection
    If r.Text = "#N/A" Then
        r.Value = r.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

The data that I want to clean is in the area AL7:AS191. The area is marked, but it doesn't seem like the loop is running. The N/A values are still there.

I have tried to do as the answer by Gary's Student suggest here:
[Changing #N/A values in Excel to last non-error value in the spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879818/changing-n-a-values-in-excel-to-last-non-error-value-in-the-spreadsheet)

Does it need minor adjustments?

All the best,
Christoffer

Comment: Have you tried `For Each r In range("AL7:AS191")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using Select (see [How to avoid using select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)), declare what range or cell you are working with.

Something like...

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim LastRow as Long
Dim LastColumn As Long


With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 38).End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = .Cells(7, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set myRange = .Range("AL7", .Cells(LastRow,LastColumn))
End with

Dim myCell as Variant

For Each myCell In myRange
    If myCell.Text = "#N/A" Then
        myCell.Value = myCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Of course, this set's `myRange` rather dynamically, if the columns to check through are always the same, you can set the range like so:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 38).End(xlUp).Row
    Set myRange = .Range("AL7:AS" & LastRow)
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help. It uses the native `ISNA()` function to test for an `#N/A` value.

```
Sub FixData()
    Dim cl As Range, rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("AL7:AS191")

    For Each cl In rng
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(cl) Then
            cl = cl.Offset(-1, 0).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This assumes a fixed range i.e. `Range("AL7:AS191")`.

You can dynamically size that range by using your original code (with `xlDown` etc).

A final point: you can use `Range("AL7").CurrentRegion` to select the entire block of cells (so long as they are a non-contiguous block).